# where do i find input folder on pandas

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I put my csv files on `users\download` section. It worked before but now it doesn't.

Where is input folder ? Iis it in `c:drive`? Although I put the files on `c:drive`but it didn't work.

Please help this poor beginner newbie

The error is as follows:

---

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1a5393e8acd8> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 train = pd.read_csv('input/train.csv')
      4 test = pd.read_csv('input/test.csv')

C:\Download\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    608     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    609 
--> 610     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    611 
    612 

C:\Download\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    460 
    461     # Create the parser.
--> 462     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    463 
    464     if chunksize or iterator:

C:\Download\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    817             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    818 
--> 819         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    820 
    821     def close(self):

C:\Download\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1048             )
   1049         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1050         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1051 
   1052     def _failover_to_python(self):

C:\Download\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1865 
   1866         # open handles
-> 1867         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
   1868         assert self.handles is not None
   1869         for key in ("storage_options", "encoding", "memory_map", "compression"):

C:\Download\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
   1360         Let the readers open IOHanldes after they are done with their potential raises.
   1361         """
-> 1362         self.handles = get_handle(
   1363             src,
   1364             "r",

C:\Download\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    640                 errors = "replace"
    641             # Encoding
--> 642             handle = open(
    643                 handle,
    644                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input/train.csv'
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the solution? Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to know the relative position of your `input` directory with respect to your notebook.

However, even without knowing your directory structure, you could use absolute paths. You said that your files are in `users\download`.
In Windows the path should be something like this if I am correct:

```
path_to_csv = 'C:\Users\your_user_name\Downloads\input\test.csv'
test = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
```

Just change `your_user_name` with YOUR user name.

**Tip:** you can find the absolute path of every folder in your computer by opening the folder and clicking on the bar that is showing you your current position. Doing this will show you the full path.